# Shared library internal

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, loader

I wish to know how the Shared library works I am asking in terms of Symbol table reference.
Is it like when we include a shared library it exports the Symbol table to process then based on some pointers we execute the respective function.

What is the meaning of Shared library Strip ?

Edit :- I wish to know that how shared library works when it get loaded into the memory.\
         When a function lets say Fun() get called from the application which has def in library. then how this linking happen . I hope now its clear.

Comment: Could you clarify your question - I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programs make calls to a shared library through a Procedure Linkage Table, which is filled in by the dynamic linker/loader [`ld.so`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) based on the information in the dynamic symbol table and relocation entries.  On Linux this data is stored in programs and libraries in the [`ELF`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/elf.5.html) format, which you can inspect using programs like [`objdump`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.19/binutils/objdump.html) and [`readelf`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.19/binutils/readelf.html).

[This Linux Journal article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6463) has a basic overview.  For more detailed information check out Ulrich Drepper's excellent paper [How To Write Shared Libraries](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf), and the Solaris [Linker and Libraries Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/index.html).

Comment: Another really in depth, though non-free, explanation can be found in the book [Linkers & Loaders](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1558604960) by John R. Levine.